# Multi Element Sort XmlDocument [WITHOUT LINQ]

Tags: xml, xpath, c#-3.0, xmldocument

I have below Xml structure.

```
<Root>
<Customers>
<Customer>
<ID1>100</ID1>
<ID2>5555</ID2>
<OtherElements />
</Customer>
<Customer>
<ID1>200</ID1>
<ID2>445</ID2>
<OtherElements />
</Customer>
<Customer>
<ID1>30</ID1>
<ID2>58878</ID2>
<OtherElements />
</Customer>
<Customers>
</Root>
```

I would like to re-arrange Customer Nodes with ID1 ASC, AND ID2 ASC sorting Order.
Please help me to achieve this without XSLT and LINQ.

Thanks

Comment: Post a well-formed XML sample to start with, currently your sample has one `<Customer>` start tag but several `</Customer>` end tags, so that is not a well-formed document.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well the .NET framework's XPath/XSLT implementation exposes a sort feature on `XPathExpression`:

```
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load("file.xml");

        XPathExpression customers = XPathExpression.Compile("/Root/Customers/Customer");
        customers.AddSort("ID1", XmlSortOrder.Ascending, XmlCaseOrder.LowerFirst, "", XmlDataType.Number);
        customers.AddSort("ID2", XmlSortOrder.Ascending, XmlCaseOrder.LowerFirst, "", XmlDataType.Number);

        XmlElement parent = doc.DocumentElement["Customers"];
        foreach (XPathNavigator cust in doc.CreateNavigator().Select(customers))
        {
            parent.AppendChild(cust.UnderlyingObject as XmlNode);
        }

        doc.Save(Console.Out); // for testing, use Save("file.xml") to save
```

With the input being

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<Root>
<Customers>
<Customer>
<ID1>100</ID1>
<ID2>5555</ID2>
<OtherElements />
</Customer>
  <Customer>
<ID1>200</ID1>
<ID2>445</ID2>
<OtherElements />
</Customer>
  <Customer>
<ID1>30</ID1>
<ID2>58878</ID2>
<OtherElements />
</Customer>
</Customers>
</Root>
```

the output is

```
<Root>
  <Customers>
    <Customer>
      <ID1>30</ID1>
      <ID2>58878</ID2>
      <OtherElements />
    </Customer>
    <Customer>
      <ID1>100</ID1>
      <ID2>5555</ID2>
      <OtherElements />
    </Customer>
    <Customer>
      <ID1>200</ID1>
      <ID2>445</ID2>
      <OtherElements />
    </Customer>
  </Customers>
</Root>
```